# What hardware specs do I need to run a 3-node Apache Cassandra cluster at production level? Do I need to get a different server for each node?

Tags: cassandra

I'm a beginner in Cassandra, and I'm trying to use Apache Cassandra to store a lot of data I'm receiving from a bunch of sensors. I need to get my own server to store data with my own server rather than using cloud options like AWS or Azure. I have been unable to find any example hardware setups, or any hardware recommendations and their prices.

I am more of a software engineer and I don't know much about how to set up servers from scratch. Because the hardware can get a bit pricey, I want to make sure I am getting the exact hardware I need.

I've done research about hardware, and most of them seem to suggest the following specs *per node*:

- CPU (8 or more cores for typical production servers)
- At least 32GB of ECC RAM
- 500GB~4TB SSD --> https://serverfault.com/questions/655730/cassandra-do-more-storage-size-needs-more-cpu-and-ram

The suggestions are all hardware specs for each *node*, and not for how these nodes can be set up together for a cluster. There are 2 options for cluster hardware that I can think of:

1. 1 server with high CPU, high RAM, multiple SSDs --> Run all 3 nodes on one server.
2. 3 servers each with lower CPU, lower RAM --> Run 1 node per server.

What are the performance tradeoffs for both #1 and #2, and which is more recommended? **And what type of server / computer shoould I get for each option?** Are there any other setups?

Comment: Aside from this being off-topic here as a non-programming question: even on dba stack exchange, this is likely off-topic as opinion-based, and recommendation-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this probably belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassandra), but I can answer this...

It depends on what your transactional throughput looks like.  I've seen people build Cassandra clusters on Raspberry Pis, but I wouldn't recommend that for prod.

I can say, that **you definitely want each node to have its own machine** instance.  If anything, that's necessary just to maintain uptime in the event of a hardware failure.  The other drawback of multiple nodes on each machine is that they'll be competing for disk I/O.  In high write throughput scenarios, disk IOPS becomes a bottleneck, and that will really hurt if all 3 nodes are trying to use the same physical disk.

If you build 3 nodes on 8 CPU cores and 32GB of RAM (w/ SSDs), that should be good.  Depending on your network and data model, I would expect you could support somewhere around 5k to 10k ops/second.  Again, it depends on things other than just your hardware specs, so that may vary.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll make sure to use dba.stackexchange.com next time! It's my first time asking a question on platforms like this so I just didn't know where to ask